# Creating many threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, simulation, java-threads

I want to simulate human population & for that I want to assign a thread to each individual. (This count should go to billion) 
Each thread will behave as individual and its end will declare that human dead.
I have implemented this using simple thread creation & also by thread pooling. But after some point of time thread allocation just ceases to happen in both the methods. (say after 150000 threads). 
I know java threads are bound by OS threads in 1:1 ratio & it will pose a problem.
What other approach will best simulate this problem?

Comment: That's just unreasonable. A thread doing nothing roughly consumes 1MB of RAM. Just having 1000 threads would need 1GB of memory. 1 billion would mean 1 million GB or memory. Even assuming each person you want to model takes only 16 bytes (that's less than what an Integer needs), you would need 16GB of RAM already. Unless you can buy some supercomputers and hire highly competent experts in the subject, you can't do what you want to do.

Comment: What does a human do in your simulation? Maybe you could have several worker threads organizing a lot more than just 1 human.

Comment: if a man has no live activity, it is not a good idea to allocate a thread to represent a person, even though they have live activities, after certain number of thread creation, one person would few minutes to take the next breath. so you should come up with a different model.

Comment: @Meini  
Humans just find a mate & produce another human (i.e another thread) & die out

Comment: It certainly looks like a bad idea with threads. I thought I can play with them @JBNizet

Comment: @pankaj If your humans have a predictable fate e.g. the time of death is already known at the moment of birth and when they meet for reproduction you shouldn't necessarily need more than one thread, you just workoff events (e.g. BirthEvent, DeathEvent) in a timeline. Although since you have billions of humans in your simulation it would be usefull to have more than one worker thread accessing a concurrent timeline - something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem. But note: this is no real time simulation.

Answer (score 4):

You can have a look at the actor model which would be more adapted than threads in your situation.

In particular, akka is open source and well known for its implementation of this pattern : https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/guide/actors-intro.html